# error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ptrProgressBarColor'

Tags: android

this is my file styles.xml

```
<style name="Widget.Custom.PtrHeader" parent="android:Widget">

    <item name="ptrProgressBarColor">@color/blue</item>

</style>


<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppThemeLight">

    <item name="ptrHeaderStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.PtrHeader</item>

</style>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
package="org.droidupnp"

android:versionCode="12"

android:versionName="2.1.0" >

<uses-sdk

    android:minSdkVersion="14"

    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

how to resolve this problem :

error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'ptrHeaderStyle'. styles.xml  /Main/res/values    line 77 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: wow!! where did you get this??

Comment: Did you define the attribute anywhere, e.g. <attr name="ptrHeaderStyle" format="reference" />?

Comment: I downloaded the DroidUpnp project from : [link](https://github.com/trishika/DroidUPnP), i add to eclipse and when   try to run this project eclipse show me this error